# Form with input boxes packed together

Tags: forms, input-fields, names, fields

I'm wondering if there is an official name for this style of the form:

[image]

Example uses: https://www.tumblr.com/login OR https://www.tumblr.com/register where the input boxes are packed together with a line in between.

Comment: The number of times I've had to click outside the box to see what field I am typing in. Hate this 'design'.

Comment: It seems to be a fancy fieldset?

Comment: Forms without any space between fields that look like your example? I think the name is bad UX experience.

Answer (score 7):

I think it mimics iOS UI style (at least I don't remember such a component before iOS, please correct me if you have some other information):

[image] 
[source](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/UITableView/)

It is UITableView with style Grouped.

Or you can call it "text field group".

Answer (score 6):

They could be referred to as **Grouped Form Fields**.

It is partly a design trend. I think most people would argue that while it may be visually pleasing, it is not great from a usability standpoint. You could closely group fields without needing to combine them in that way. For example, someone may not realize that they need to tap again to type in a second part of the field.

---

[image: Grouped Form Fields]